# How to break out of a Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, actionlistener

I have a thread to show and increment a swing progress bar, display some progress information and perform some database operations. The thread is started from an event on a button in the following way:

```
`public class SetupPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame
 {
     private static Thread myThread = null; 
     private void initComponents() 
     {
        setupPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        setupBtn = new JButton("Save Setup"); 

        //.. all the other swing components needed..

        setupBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
           {
               myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
               {
               @Override
               public void run() 
               {                           
                 try 
                 { 
                  //update db, progress bar, display messages, sleep
                      myThread.yield();
                 } 
                 catch (InterruptedException e) 
                 {
                      Logger.getLogger(SwingProgressBar.class.getName())
                      .log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                      System.exit(0);
                 }

              }
            });
            myThread.start();
          }
        });`
```

I would like the thread to stop running after all the operations on the database and progress bar are finished, but as thread.stop() can't be used anymore and thread.yield() dosen't work, I don't know how to break out of the thread.

I have tried forcing errors such as divide by zero after the thread yield in the hope that I can catch such errors and break the thread, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Note that you can't update the progress bar and update messages from your separate thread directly (you could but you'd run into many race conditions). You can only do UI manipulation on the UI thread. You can schedule some work on the UI thread from your database update thread using `EventQueue.invokeLater`.

Comment: The thread **will** stop once its program flow has completed, just like any method will exit once it has run out of code. Your question is not showing what's preventing this from happening.

Comment: Note:  `myThread.yield()` does not do anything to `myThread`:  It operates on the thread that called it.  `yield()` is not an instance method:  It's a `static` method of the `Thread` class.

Answer (score 3):

Swing components can be accessed by only one thread at a time. Generally, this thread is the event-dispatching thread. When you need concurrency, you can use [SwingWorker.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), some codes about using swingworker to get data from other location and update it in progress bar

```
   class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    /*
     * Main task. Executed in background thread.you can use it to communicate with database
     */
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int progress = 0;
        //Initialize progress property.
        setProgress(0);
        while (progress < 100) {
            //Sleep for up to one second.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            //Make random progress.
            progress += random.nextInt(10);
            setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Executed in event dispatching thread
     */
    @Override
    public void done() {
        // you can do any operation about swing component
    }
}

// to execute the task and update the progress bar
Task  task = new Task();
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){

        /**
         * Invoked when task's progress property changes.
         */
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
                int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
                progressBar.setValue(progress);
                taskOutput.append(String.format(
                        "Completed %d%% of task.\n", task.getProgress()));
            } 

        }

    });
    task.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have a boolean flag in the parent class that can be checked from the Thread.

e.g.

```
final private boolean doStop = false;
private static Thread myThread = null;

public void run() 
{                           
    if (doStop) return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread can be internally stopped by using one of these methods:

- The run method hits a return subroutine;
- Run method finishes and returns implicitly.

You can also do it externally, by calling the Thread object's `interrupt()` method, instead of `Thread.stop();`